# Message: Entities not found for JPA configuration: 'default' within packages [example.micronaut]

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

was trying micronaut with [this example](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-jpa-hibernate-gradle-java.zip) from there official [website](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-jpa-hibernate-gradle-java.html) but got the following error.

> Message: Entities not found for JPA configuration: 'default' within packages [example.micronaut]. Check that you have correctly specified a package containing JPA entities within the "jpa.default.entity-scan.packages" property in your application configuration and that those entities are either compiled with Micronaut or a build time index produced with @Introspected(packages="foo.bar", includedAnnotations=Entity.class) declared on your Application class
> Path Taken: SessionFactory.hibernateSessionFactory([SessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder]) --> SessionFactoryBuilder.hibernateSessionFactoryBuilder([MetadataSources metadataSources],ValidatorFactory validatorFactory,Interceptor hibernateInterceptor)
> io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Bean definition [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [org.hibernate.boot.SessionFactoryBuilder]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set property `jpa.default.entity-scan.packages` in application.yml.

For example, here you need to set

```
jpa.default.entity-scan.packages=example.micronaut.domain
```

Comment: It looks like, that the entity is not being found if Jakarta is used.
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
@Entity

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the docs - https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/#hibernateJpaAnnotations. So I guess that when using micronaut-data-jpa the annotations should be with javax.*